# SQL UNION only returning result from first SELECT

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, union

I am attempting to perform a SQL call that fetches a row from one table and counts the records from another table. However, the call only returns results from the first SELECT. Code is as follows:

```
$sql = "SELECT row_1 FROM table_1 WHERE user_id = :user_id
UNION
SELECT COUNT(row_2) as new_var FROM table_2 WHERE user_id = :user_id";

$query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
$params = array('user_id' => $var);
$query->execute($params);
$result = $query->fetch();
```

The result should be:

```
array(
  'row_1' => val_1,
  'new_var' => val_2
)
```

The solution to the problem is undoubtedly simple, yet eludes me! Thanks in advance!

**Solved!**

It would appear UNION was inappropriate in this case. Revamping the SQL call to use JOIN solved the issue:

```
SELECT table_1.row_1, COUNT(table_2.row_2) AS new_var 
FROM table_1 LEFT JOIN table_2
ON table_1.user_id = table_2.user_id AND table_1.user_id = :user_id
```

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Have you try `UNION ALL`? `UNION` eliminated duplicate rows.

Comment: What datatype is row_1 in table_1, it has to match the datatype of `count(user_id)`

Comment: @RubahMalam, UNION ALL doesn't seem to rectify the issue.

Comment: @RiggsFolly, row_1 and count(row_2) (count(user_id) was a typo) are indeed both integers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your script, you seem like you want 2 columns. One with `row_1` and one with `count(user_id)`. If so, `UNION` is not the correct operator.

Your code as it stands returns 2 rows with one column each.
But in your PHP you called `$query->fetch()`. That only returns the first row.

#### Option 1

Fetch both rows with `$query->fetchAll()`

#### Option 2

Make it two columns by using `JOIN` instead of a `UNION`

Comment: Join was effectively the way to go!

Answer (score 1):

If I had to guess, then `row_1` is an integer, and one of the values exactly matches the count.

`UNION` not only combines two tables/subqueries.  It also removes duplicates.  So, my first guess for fixing the problem is:

```
SELECT row_1 FROM table_1 WHERE user_id = :user_id
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(user_id) as new_var FROM table_2 WHERE user_id = :user_id
```

Note:  You should also identify which rows are the original data rows and which is the summary row.  Result sets in SQL are *unordered*.  There is no guarantee that the rows will be returned in a particular order -- unless you use `ORDER BY`.